# How to edit django DRF API code that queries DB and returns data, to read in a file and upload data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know there are a lot of questions like this out there, I am just really confused about my specific case.

I have a `employee_models.py` file with three classes; one with employee names and one with dept details, and then one that combines these two and some other info:

```
from django.db import models
class employee_name(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class employee_dept(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   employee = models.ForeignKey('employee_name',blank=True, null=True)
   dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   time_in_dept = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   due_review = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class full_employee_record(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey('employee_name',blank=True, null=True)
    dept = models.ForeignKey('employee_dept',blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    benefits = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from employee_models import employee_name,employee_dept

class EmployeeNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = employee_name
        fields = "__all__"

class EmployeeDeptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = employee_dept
        fields = "__all__"

class FullEmployeeRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = full_employee_record
        fields = "__all__"
```

and a Views.py file:

```
class EmployeeNameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = employee_name.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeNameSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, CuratedDataPermission)
    pagination_class = LongPagination


class EmployeeDeptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = employee_dept.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeDeptSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, CuratedDataPermission)
    pagination_class = LongPagination


class FullEmployeeRecordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = full_employee_record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FullEmployeeRecordSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, CuratedDataPermission)
    pagination_class = LongPagination
```

and a URLs page:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from employee.DRF import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'employee_name', views.EmployeeNameViewSet, basename="EmployeeName")
router.register(r'employee_dept', views.EmployeeDeptViewSet, basename="EmployeeDept")
router.register(r'full_employee_record', views.FullEmployeeRecordViewSet, basename="FullEmployeeRecord")
```

I have an API working where I can read in a set of params, and it will query the database and return the objects. However, now, I have a text file that I want to upload:

```
first_name   surname   initial   dept_name  time_in_service    address   benefits
john         waters    L         finance    2 months           add1      health
kevin        smith     M.N.      finance    5 years            add2      health,rent
adam         kane      B.        audit      1.7 years          add3      health,pension
```

I know how to do this with SQLAlchemy, but I want to develop a DRF API method for uploading this data. So I want to:

> 1. Develop a DRF API way of uploading, but two, in particular:
> 2. Have some sort of automapping function, if possible, where I can (this might be unrealistic), just match each field in the model to the
>      field in the upload file, and then all of the mapping for all the
>      tables is done automatically.

I can see a lot of docs on how to upload different types of files e.g. [here](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/uploading-images-drf/) and [here](https://medium.com/@jxstanford/django-rest-framework-file-upload-e4bc8de669c0).
I am really struggling to understand how I relate this to my own project.

My specific question is what code do I add to what parts of the above code, to allow me to read in a tab-delimited text file via API and have it be uploaded/how do I call it. I already have an API working that allows be to query what's already in the database, it's just going in the opposite direction and uploading via the DRF API that I am really struggling with.